# Conflict of id in cancelling multiple alarms in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

My app lets the users to set reminders for taking medications at specific times.
There is no problem in setting these alarms. I am having difficulty in cancelling these alarms at a **later point of time in another activity**.

This is my code for setting the alarms:

```
private void setAlarms() {
    Intent myIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("MedName",medication_name);
    myIntent.setAction("b5.project.medibro.receivers.AlarmReceiver");
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    int counter=0;
    for(String timer: timers){
        //timer is a string of the form "hh:mm"
        try {
            String[] comps=timer.split(":");
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(comps[0]));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(comps[1]));
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            //Date date= dateFormat.parse(startDate + " " + timer);
            Log.d(TAG,comps[0]+" "+comps[1]+ "Alarm Time: " + cal.getTime().toString());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), counter, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent);

            Log.d(TAG,"Counter: "+counter);
            counter++;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG,"Time Parsing error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the counter is the id for pendingIntents belonging to ONE Medicine.
But when there are multiple medicines, the pending intents will have same ids.(counter values)

Can anyone suggest an alternate/efficient method to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the counter value somewhere when the loop finishes. And fetch it at the start of the loop.
Save them as a comma separated string of integers containing the counter values of 
all intents related to a specific medicine.
for example:

```
String a = "0,1,2,3,4";
putString("MEDICINE_1",a);
```

then

```
getString("MEDICINE_1").split(',')
```

Comment: But what about "MEDICINE_2" even that will have same counter values (0,1,2,3,4) and I will not be able to fetch the right pending intent as the counter values override each other

Comment: move the initialization of counter to 0 out of the method. that way the counter values won't start from 0 when adding a new medicine.